# Can not cast an object to parcelable

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, classcastexception, parcelable

I have an `Intent` service. In `onHandleIntent` I want to put an object of type `List<Trends>` to an Intent, so that I can send this Intent via `sendBroadcast` as shown in the code below.

The issue I am facing now is when I put the list object to a `Bundle` and cast it to `Parcelable`, I receive the below posted error.

**My Code**:

```
Intent intentBroadcast = new Intent();
Bundle bundleList = new Bundle();
bundleList.putParcelable("data", (Parcelable) this.mTrendsList); //java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
intentBroadcast.putExtra(TwitterTrendsAPIService.CONST_INTENT_KEY, bundleList);
sendBroadcast(intentBroadcast);
```

**The Error**:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
at com.example.pc_amr.twittertrendsnearlocation.services.TwitterTrendsAPIService.onHandleIntent(TwitterTrendsAPIService.java:86)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only put objects of classes that implement `Parcelable`.

For more info [read this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable).

Answer (score 0):

The `putParcelable()` method is being used wrong here. This method can be used to save a single object of a class that implements the `Parcelable` interface. To save an array, you need to use `putParcelableArrayList()` method.

Comment: And make sure that the class whose array list you are saving, implements the `Parcelable` interface.

Comment: do u mean that, since i have list<Trends> the class Trends should implement Parcelable

Comment: Yes, the `Trends` class should implement the `Parcelable` interface. After doing that, you can use the `putParcelableArrayList()` to save the array in the bundle. No need to type cast it. You can checkout the official [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) to see how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass an ArrayList then I'd go with implementing Parcelable